# mxgraph how to get and set label position of edge?

Tags: mxgraph

I want to save the edge label position, and I find `mxEdgeHandler.prototype.moveLabel` can get the label position,but how to set label position after `graph.insertEdge`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `mxGeometry offset`.

Extract from the [mxGeometry JS API](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGeometry-js.html#mxGeometry.offset)

```
For edges, this holds the offset (in pixels) from the position defined
by <x> and <y> on the edge.  For relative geometries (for vertices), this
defines the absolute offset from the point defined by the relative coordinates.
For absolute geometries (for vertices), this defines the offset for the label.
Default is null.
```

If you use the `insertEdge` function, you cannot directly set the offset, but you can update it on the edge returned by the function

```
const mxEdge = graph.insertEdge(parent, id, 'label', source, target, style);
mxCell.geometry.offset = new this.mxPoint(relativeLabelX, relativeLabelY);
```

Notice that you may also have to set the x and y values of the geometry of the edge as they seem not set on egde creation.

You can also create the edge first then add it to the graph (this is what the insertEdge function does for you). When create the edge mxCell you can set its geometry prior adding it to the graph, or after adding it as when calling insertEdge.

See also the [mxGraph 4.1.1 insertEdge code](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph2/blob/mxgraph-4_1_1/javascript/src/js/view/mxGraph.js#L4562)